# How to add the very last border on the sub menu items

Tags: html, css

I need your help.

As it stands right now, I have a CCS menu which looks great and all, but I do want to complete the box look on my sub menu items. That being the case, as it stands right now, the bottom border is missing from the last item. How can this be modified using CSS coding?

Html code:

```
<div id="menuwrap">
  <ul class="navbar">

     <li><a href="#">B2B Portal</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">B2B Portal</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Secure Data-Driven Listings</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Secure Shopping Cart</a></li>
        </ul>         
     </li>

     <li><a href="#">Retrievals</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Data Listing</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Web Scheduling</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Mapping Application</a></li>
        </ul>         
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Reporting</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#" >Ad Hoc Report</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Drill Down Report</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Ranking Report</a></li>
        </ul>         
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Business Intelligence</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Business Dashboard</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Web Pivot Table</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Interactive Report</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">What-If Analysis</a></li>
        </ul>         
     </li>
     <li><a href="#">Data Maintenance</a>
        <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Database CRUD</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Database Update</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Order Entry</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Drag-and-Drop Application</a></li>
        </ul>         
     </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar     {
        height: 18px;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        position: absolute;
}

        .navbar li  {
                    width: 135px; 
                    float: left; 
                    text-align: center; 
                    list-style: none; 

        }

            .navbar a   {                           
                    width: 133px;
                    height: 19px;
                    display: block;
                    text-decoration:none;
                    line-height: 15px;
                    color: #ffffff;
                    border: 1px solid rgb(110,110,110);             
            }

                .navbar li:hover, a:hover   {
                    background-color: #ffffff;
                    color: #000000;
                }

                .navbar li ul   {
                                display: none;                          
                                margin: 0;
                                padding: 0;                         
                                }

                .navbar li:hover ul {
                            display: block;
                }


                .navbar li ul li a  {
                            color: #000000;
                            border-top: 0;
                            border-bottom: 0;
                }

                .navbar li ul li a:hover {
                    background-color: rgb(255,231,162);
                }

                .navbar li:hover > a {
                    background: rgb(255,231,162);
                    color: #000000;
                }



</style>
```

Comment: `.navbar li:last-child (border:1px solid red)` and for the child items `.navbar ul li:last-child (border:1px solid blue)`

Comment: Have you looked at CSS `:last-of-type` and/or `last-child` selectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the :last-child or :last-of-type pseudo classes - see http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp

and http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-of-type.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this: `.navbar li > ul > li:last-child {border-bottom:1px solid black;}`

Also, you could add this `height: 100%;` to your  `.navbar li ul li a` selector, so your text wont overflow over the borders, to some of your links.